# UPDATE OR INSERT values from a datagrid checkbox into database

Tags: c#, database, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I Have a Datagrid with checkbox columns in WPF, and I want to insert values into the database when edited on the Datagrid like if a checkbox is clicked, One method I found is to

`foreach (checkedbox in checkbox column) {insert a 1}` ,this is just roughly written

but I wanted to know was there any efficient method, like binding with properties but for inserting thats what i do to read values from the database,  i set the datacontext of the datagrid to the result set and bind the columns to the properties of object this is to read, is there anyway to also update values, the database I am using is MySQL

## READ METHOD

**METHOD IS DATA ACCESS LAYER**

```
public List<Selection> ReadSel()                            
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = GetConnection())
        {
            var output = connection.Query<Selection>("S_S", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return output.ToList();                        
        }                                                            <--- (using DAPPER ORM)
                                                       
    }

 (S_S is a stored procedure that returns values for 5 columns)
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
 private void dtgrd_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { IDAL da = new DAL_MySQL();                              <---- (IDAL is an inetrface)
      dtgrd.DataContext = da.ReadSel();                          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I have mine set up is when I click on the check box it fires an event that checks what the database is set as and then swaps it from true to false or false to true.

Xaml

```
    <DataGrid
                    Name="IssuedCCCollection"
                    IsReadOnly="False" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    Margin="5"
                    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
                    HeadersVisibility="Column">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Certificate No" Binding="{Binding JobandVersionNo}"  Width="110"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date of Issue" Binding="{Binding DateOfIssue, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}"  Width="95"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Council" Width="80">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox
                                            Name="CertificateToCouncilSentCheck"
                                            Click="CertificateToCouncilSentCheck_Click"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IssuedToCouncil, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            Margin="30 0 0 0"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Owner" Width="80">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox
                                            Name="CertificateToOwnerSentCheck"
                                            Click="CertificateToOwnerSentCheck_Click"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IssuedtoOwner, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            Margin="30 0 0 0"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Code behind

```
    private void CertificateToCouncilSentCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (CheckBox)sender;
        RecordListModel selectedCondition = (RecordListModel)row.DataContext;
        int Id = selectedCondition.Id;
        bool currentResult = selectedCondition.IssuedToCouncil;
        if (currentResult == false)
        {
            using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var condition = db.RecordList.Find(Id);
                condition.IssuedToCouncil = true;

                db.RecordList.Update(condition);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var condition = db.RecordList.Find(Id);
                condition.IssuedToCouncil = false;

                db.RecordList.Update(condition);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting you answer, but can you please also paste RecordListModel class, I am going through it and it is really confusing without the class